# What's wrong with '2018-03-22 00:00:00" in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, timezone, dst

I want to update a date field and set it to `2018-03-22 00:00:00` but I get the following stupid error:

> Error Code: 1292.  Incorrect datetime value: '2018-03-22 00:00:00' for column 'Date' at row 158917

This is the query I use for updating:

```
update assets.transactions 
set date = date_add(date, interval 1 hour)
where date between '2018-03-21 23:00:00' and '2018-06-29 23:59:59';
```

What is wrong? I searched a lot and found out dates before `1970-01-01 00:00:01` are not supported by MySQL, that is acceptable, but a date in the middle of 2018? That's something I can't digest.

Is there any solution to make this work right?

Comment: What type is that Date column?

Comment: @fvu the column is defined as TIMESTAMP

Comment: Please include the full query.  By the way, are you really using MySQL?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes buddy, why should I lie about that xD
I updated the question and added the query.

Comment: I also tried inserting the same date in another machine, in a new table with the same TIMESTAMP field, I got the same error there too.
insert into people.test values (1, '2018-03-22 00:00:00') Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '2018-03-22 00:00:00' for column 'date' at row 1

Comment: There isn't something wrong in MySQL with that date. I created this simple fiddle that you can check: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/u5ZmAv1ymsn9d7kEBMb5Bs/1

Comment: Check for triggers , your update cannot be causing this since the earliest possible calculated date is 2018-03-24 00:00:00

Comment: @P.Salmon my mistake, the first date was `2018-03-21 23:00:00`

Comment: It's funny that `2018-03-21 00:23:00` updated to `2018-03-22 00:00:00` with no problem, dates after `2018-03-22` works fine as well, but that date is kind of mysterious.

Comment: And there are no triggers on the table

Comment: @NiVeR yes apparently it works in the fiddle but on my machines, it does not. The difference between my case and yours is that the timezone of my machines is +3:30.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you're updating a `TIMESTAMP` column. I also guess you have your MySQL instance set to a timezone with a daylight time switchover on 23-March-2018. I guess the rules of your timezone switchover in your country mean that the clock rolls over from 21-March-2018 11:59:59 to 22-March-2018 01:00:00.

So the value `2018-03-22 00:00:00` just doesn't exist.

Strange, isn't it?

Try issuing this MySQL command, to set the time zone to UTC, before doing these sorts of mass timestamp updates.

```
SET time_zone = 'UTC';
```

Don't forget to switch it back before doing other operations. Or just do those operations from a different MySQL connection.

Comment: Finally, someone came up with something that makes sense. Thanks for your answer. I'm going to check it and keep you updated.

Comment: With respect, @MahdiTahsildari, go easy on the people who tried to help you in the comments. This kind of thing happens rarely.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean to be mean. I am grateful to everyone and they are kind to help no matter their solutions work or not. I guess I wouldn't sound offensive if English wasn't my second language. In my language, such a sentence is a compliment. The lesson is taken.