# ERROR 1292 Incorrect datetime value

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I got an SQL error during importing a Database.

```
Incorrect datetime value: '2013-03-31 02:05:39' for column 'created_at' at row 1
```

What is wrong with my date?

Response to comment?

> How are you importing the database?

With `mysql -u root -p < data.sql`

> what is data type of 'created_at' column

`created_at` is from type `timestamp`.

> What timezone was in use on your old server? On your new server? Does this help?

On both servers `SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone` returns `SYSTEM`. On both server `date` shows the same date `Mon Aug  6 23:22:46 CEST 2018` and `date +"%Z %z"` returns CEST +0200.

Comment: How are you importing the database?

Comment: the date looks OK, and I cannot repro the error.

Comment: what is data type of 'created_at' column

Comment: You *may* have a daylight time switchover problem considering your offending time is in the early hours of the morning in March. What timezone was in use on your old server? On your new server? Does this help?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51464141/whats-wrong-with-2018-03-22-000000-in-mysql/51464354#51464354

Comment: +1 @O.Jones, 2013 daylight savings was on 31.03. Depending on the timezone 02:05 might be an invalid time.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I'm not aware what the `daylight switchover` is. I will investigate it.

Comment: I export the files using mysqldump and from the doc it shouldn't be a problem: `--tz-utc also protects against changes due to daylight saving time. --tz-utc is enabled by default.`